# MEQP Gives a Warning : Data load getFirstItem() method detected in loop

Tags: magento2, collection, coding-standards, factory

I want to get the First item from the collection so I have used following code. But it gives some warning on the usage of `getFirstItem()`

```
protected $_sampleFactory;

public function __construct(
   \Vendor\Module\Model\sampleFactory $sampleFactory,
) {
   $this->_sampleFactory = $sampleFactory;
}
public function execute()
{
   $collection = $this->_sampleFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("product_id", $product_id);

   $customer_id = $collection->getFirstItem()->getCustomerId();
   return $customer_id;
}
```

This code is working properly but when I checked with magento-coding-standard tool its given me the warning on usage of `getFirstItem()` as follow.

> 107 | WARNING | Data load getFirstItem() method detected in loop
>   107 | WARNING | getFirstItem does not limit the result of collection load to one item.

Anyone has any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @KeyurShah We'll try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only 1 Item from collection then you can limit the collection by using,     `$collection->setPageSize(1)` and  `$collection->setCurPage(1)` so It will fetch only 1 value from your collection. In your case you can do it like,

```
   $collection = $this->_sampleFactory->create()->getCollection()
                 ->addFieldToFilter("product_id", $product_id)
                 ->setPageSize(1)
                 ->setCurPage(1)
                 ->getFirstItem();
```

Comment: You still may receive that standard violation error, but as long as you setPageSize(1), then you should be okay.

Comment: I don't think so still It will gives the error after setting this @df2k2

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll have to double-check that then.  Perhaps I have something missing or a setting incorrect.  I do agree with your answer as the correct answer, though.

Comment: Your code is working but you have used getFirstItem() in your code.So MEQP gives me again same warning.Anyone has other solution then please upload.

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd did you find any solution regarding it.